# How to join two tables having same column name in SQL

Tags: sql

My problem is that, I have 2 tables - one original table, named `sequence`, and a temporary table, named `tempt1`. The column `seq` in the table `sequence` has all values as null by default.

The `sequence` table has following columns:

```
backuptype varchar(20),
backuptime datetime,
seq int default null
```

Now in `tempt1` table, I have some values in `seq` column which I need to update in the `seq` column of table `sequence`.

Please help me to join these two column values and update the main table `sequence`.

Comment: What RDBMS you are using??

Comment: What database? What have you tried?

Comment: so, how are the two tables related?

Comment: i am using sql server 2012...
the temporary table was created using the following query

select * into tempt1 from sequence where backuptime < @crashpt

Answer (score 2):

For `Sql-Server`, if two tables are related to each other then you could join them and update;

```
Update s
Set s.seq = t.seq
From sequence s join temp1 t 
     on s.keyColumn = t.relatedColumn
where not t.seq is null and s.seq is null
```

Comment: No problem! Are you sorted now?

Comment: But its not working... 
(0 row(s) affected)
the sequence table is not getting updated

Comment: What are the related columns of two tables?

Comment: all the columns are related.... the temporary table was created by the following query
select * into tempt1 from sequence where backuptime < @crashpt

Comment: the tempt1 table contains all the rows from sequence where the condition backuptime < @crashpt is satisfied

Comment: Join the tables using those related columns and use #tempt1 instead tempt1 if it is a temporary table. should be fine.

Comment: You need to update your question with more details about table structure and with some data from both tables.